# In the Terminal preferences, what does the "Use Style for "Copy" Command" option do?

Tags: macos, terminal

Sorry if this is a bit of a newbie question, but I couldn't find it by googling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's for the visualization purposes. For example here are two different paste styles form my Terminal:

[image]

As You see, they look differently when pasted into for example TextEdit app.

Answer (score 1):

It sets the style for copied text for **any** terminal profiles.

You can only set for **one** profile "Use Style for ”Copy“ Command” under the gear icon, and then text copied from terminal window of any profile will use the set profile's style. E.g., if you set if for Ocean profile, text copied from Grass profile will have blue instead of green background.